# Can't seem to find the correct if statement or return

Tags: java, class, if-statement, methods, return

I am trying to write a BankAccount.java class and I am almost done except for the withdraw method.  I havae left comments explaining my understanding of what the code I am writing implies, but I am having trouble finding what is causing the logic error.

The test program has account1 balance = 100 and account2 balance = 200
the withdraw amounts are account1 = 100 and account2 = 201 so obviously 100 should follow the if return and account 2 should follow the else return however that is not the case.

```
public int withdraw(double amount) {
    AccountBalance = this.AccountBalance - amount; // Setting AccountBalance to what it would be when the withdraw amount is subtracted
    if (0 < AccountBalance) // testing if 0 is less than AccountBalance
        return (int)AccountBalance; // if so then i return the new positive balance 
    else
        return (int)AccountBalance + (int)amount; //if less then 0 i return to what the balance was before withdraw was subtracted because i can't have a negative balance

}
```

This is the following output i am receiving in CMD:

```
F:\>java BankDemo
The balance of account1 is: 100.0
The balance of account2 is: 200.0
account1 information: John Smith
AccountNumber: 12345
Balance: 0.0

account2 information: John Calipari
AccountNumber: 54321
Balance: -1.0
```

The above two accounts are the same? false

Last though I have is perhaps this the error is not in this method and in a different method throughout the class.  I don't believe this is the case because i have triple checked, but if that seems like a possibility feed back would be great because I would turn focus from this method to others in my class.

Comment: Why are you casting to `int`? I think we may need to see more of your code.

Comment: Are you setting the `AccountBalance` to the amount that you return from this method at all?  If not, then how are you using the return value?  In the "negative" case, this method itself leaves `AccountBalance` as negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the rest of your code right you're doing `AccountBalance = this.AccountBalance - amount` no matter what. This is always going to alter the balance amount. When you add the value back on to the amount you don't actually set the `AccountBalance` variable back. So in the else block you want to add:

`AccountBalance = (int)AccountBalance + (int)amount;`

Making sure to select the correct  type for AccountBalance, also variables often start with lower case by convention so `accountBalance` so it might make it easier to read if its lower cased but that won't affect the actual result.

Comment: I recently just tried this and it works for making account2 200 again however; now account1 is back equal to 100 instead of 0.

Comment: You need to alter your if statement to be `<=` as 0 is a valid account balanace

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated. program running as smooth as possible now

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `if (0 > AccountBalance)` gives true if `AccountBalance` is negative and false if it's positive; not the other way around.

Comment: excuse my typo in the code i posted.  I did have it the way you suggested.  My mistake i have made the necessary edit

Answer (score 0):

your method is wrong checkout this one.

```
public int withdraw(double amount) {
    AccountBalance = this.AccountBalance - amount; 
    if (0 > AccountBalance) { // testing if 0 is greater than Account balance
   return (int)AccountBalance + (int)amount; 
    } else{ 
    return (int)AccountBalance; 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If a negative balance is an invalid state, you should not modify the member and check afterwords.

```
if (AccountBalance >= amount) {
  AccountBalance -= amount;
}
return AccountBalance;
```

(Missing type conversions to show clear code)

I think your test shows the member state (toString()?) and not the return value of the method.